# Hover Menu Delayed Close?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to add a delay on mouse out from hover menu. Here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYjzVb

Please notice that I have used these lines for CSS transitions:

```
-webkit-transition: visibility 0.65s ease-in;
-moz-transition: visibility 0.65s ease-in;
```

But this doesn't works. I am using Chrome browser, tried to view it in Firefox too but that doesn't helps.

Please help!

Comment: You need JavaScript for this.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Can you please post an answer what code should I use to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: Sure, I'll create an answer. Just wanted to know that you're okay with a JavaScript solution.

Comment: I am satisfied with either jQuery or simple prototype. More happy if some CSS do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JavaScript for handling `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and use `setTimeout()` for the delay(`5s`) on `mouseleave` event.

You could set the delay through the variable `delay`.

<kbd>**[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/WbGYPw)**</kbd>

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.drop_menu > li');
var delay = 5000;

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    var c = this.children
    for (j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
      if (c[j].localName == 'ul') {
        c[j].style.display = 'block';
        c[j].style.position = 'absolute';
      }
    }
  });
  items[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    mouseLeave(this, j);
  });
}

function mouseLeave(el, j) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var c = el.children;
    for (j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
      if (c[j].localName == 'ul') {
        c[j].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }, delay)
}
```

```css
.drop_menu {
  background: #10BDF5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 25px;
}
.drop_menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.drop_menu li a {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
/* Submenu */

.drop_menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.drop_menu > li {
  position: relative;
}
.drop_menu li:hover {
  background: #51C7ED;
}
.drop_menu li ul {
  left: 0px;
  top: 28px;
  background: #51C7ED;
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #1292BB;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.drop_menu li ul li a {
  padding: 1px 4px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-indent: 11px;
  background-color: #10BDF5;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover {
  background: #51C7ED;
}
#panel {
  background: #10BDF5;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #30B3DE;
  padding: 3px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <ul class="drop_menu">
    <li><a href="upgrade.php">Upgrade Account</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link.php">Link One</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="link.php">link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="link.php">link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="link.php">link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link.php">Link Two</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks chipChocolate.py, I am really thankful for your time and answer.

Comment: @ImranOmer - No Worries. :)

Answer (score 2):

**1- WITHOUT ANIMATION:**

```css
/**RESETING BROWSER STYLE*/
*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0}

/**SETTING THE ROOT ELEMENT BACKGROUND*/
:root{background: #ccc}

/**REMOVING THE STYLE ON ALL LIST IN [id=panel]*/
[id=panel] li{
    list-style-type: none
}

/**INIT OUR DROP MENU*/
.drop_menu {
    background: #10BDF5;
    height: 25px
}
/* SUBMENU position:absolute AND OPACITY INSTEAD OF VISIBILITY and ease-out not ease-in*/
.drop_menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 28px;
    height: 0; /**SET THIS TO ZERO SINCE WE CAN'T ANIMATE display: none*/
    overflow: hidden; /**YOU NEED THIS TO HIDE THE LIST*/
    background:#51C7ED;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 0; /**DO NOT DISPLAY THE LIST ON INIT STATE*/
    transition:opacity 0 5s linear, height 0 5s linear,border-bottom 0 5s linear/**TRANSITION ON OPACITY WITHOUT DELAY BUT ON HEIGHT WITH A DELAY GREATER OR EGAL THE OPACITY ANIMATION DURATION*/
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
    transition:height 0s ease-out ;/**TRANSITION ONLY ON HEIGHT*/
    opacity: 1;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #1292BB;
    height: 76px /**SET THE HEIGHT ON MOUVE IN*/
}
/**GIVING position: relative TO THE PARENT OF OUR UNORDERED LIST SINCE IT HAS position:absolute */

.drop_menu li { float:left; position: relative}
.drop_menu li a {
    padding:3px 6px;
    display:block;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 22px;
}




.drop_menu li:hover { position:relative; background:#51C7ED; }

.drop_menu ul a {
    padding:1px 4px;
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-indent:11px;
    background-color:#10BDF5;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
    padding:1px 4px;
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-indent:11px;
    background-color:#10BDF5;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { background:#51C7ED }

#panel {
    background: #10BDF5;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #30B3DE;
    padding: 3px 4px
        
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
    <ul class="drop_menu">
    <li><a href="upgrade.php">Upgrade Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="link.php">Link One</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="link.php">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="link.php">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="link.php">link</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link.php">Link Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**2- WITH ANIMATION**

```css
/**RESETING BROWSER STYLE*/
*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0}

/**SETTING THE ROOT ELEMENT BACKGROUND*/
:root{background: #ccc}

/**REMOVING THE STYLE ON ALL LIST IN [id=panel]*/
[id=panel] li{
    list-style-type: none
}

/**INIT OUR DROP MENU*/
.drop_menu {
    background: #10BDF5;
    height: 25px
}
/* SUBMENU position:absolute AND OPACITY INSTEAD OF VISIBILITY and ease-out not ease-in*/
.drop_menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 28px;
    height: 0; /**SET THIS TO ZERO SINCE WE CAN'T ANIMATE display: none*/
    overflow: hidden; /**YOU NEED THIS TO HIDE THE LIST*/
    background:#51C7ED;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 0; /**DO NOT DISPLAY THE LIST ON INIT STATE*/
    transition:opacity 0.65s ease-out, height 0 0.68s linear /**TRANSITION ON OPACITY WITHOUT DELAY BUT ON HEIGHT WITH A DELAY GREATER OR EGAL THE OPACITY ANIMATION DURATION*/
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
    transition:height 0s ease-out ;/**TRANSITION ONLY ON HEIGHT*/
    opacity: 1;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #1292BB;
    height: 76px /**SET THE HEIGHT ON MOUVE IN*/
}
/**GIVING position: relative TO THE PARENT OF OUR UNORDERED LIST SINCE IT HAS position:absolute */

.drop_menu li { float:left; position: relative}
.drop_menu li a {
    padding:3px 6px;
    display:block;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 22px;
}




.drop_menu li:hover { position:relative; background:#51C7ED; }

.drop_menu ul a {
    padding:1px 4px;
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-indent:11px;
    background-color:#10BDF5;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
    padding:1px 4px;
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-indent:11px;
    background-color:#10BDF5;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { background:#51C7ED }

#panel {
    background: #10BDF5;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #30B3DE;
    padding: 3px 4px
        
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
    <ul class="drop_menu">
    <li><a href="upgrade.php">Upgrade Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="link.php">Link One</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="link.php">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="link.php">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="link.php">link</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link.php">Link Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But the issue is when mouse comes near to the area of hovered menu it opens, however it should hover / opens when mouse comes over the `link` instead of the area near to the link. You may notice this by running this code on this stackoverflow page too

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I want the way like it opens in here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYjzVb , and after opening it closes after 5 seconds when mouse out. Can we do like this?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py What are you talking about of cause there is delay you can change it as you want.

Comment: Thanks @Tambo, I am really thankful for your time and answer.